# Why does not init:stop() terminate directly?

Tags: datetime, erlang

My code for display all days in this year.

I don't understand why `if NewSec =< EndSec -> init:stop() end` did not execute the first time in run_calendar?

I expect init:stop() could be executed first time but it is not. 
What is wrong?

Code:

```
-module(cal).
-export([main/0]).

main() ->
    StartSec = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{2009,1,1},{0,0,0}}),
    EndSec = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{2009,12,31},{0,0,0}}),
    run_calendar(StartSec,EndSec).

run_calendar(CurSec, EndSec) -> 
    {Date,_Time} = calendar:gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(CurSec),
    io:format("~p~n", [Date]),
    NewSec = CurSec + 60*60*24,
    if NewSec =< EndSec -> init:stop() end,
    run_calendar(NewSec, EndSec).
```

Result:

```
wk# erlc cal.erl 
wk# erl -noshell -s cal main
{2009,1,1}
{2009,1,2}
{2009,1,3}
{2009,1,4}
{2009,1,5}
...
{2009,12,22}
{2009,12,23}
{2009,12,24}
{2009,12,25}
{2009,12,26}
{2009,12,27}
{2009,12,28}
{2009,12,29}
{2009,12,30}
{2009,12,31}
wk#
```

Comment: Why don't you just change the if to **not** call `run_calendar/2` recursively: `if NewSec =< EndSec -> ok; true -> run_calendar(NewSec, EndSec) end.` and your program will exit normally without quirky behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that init:stop() is an asynchronous process that will attempt to shut down the runtime smoothly. According to [the docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/init.html), "All applications are taken down smoothly, all code is unloaded, and all ports are closed before the system terminates."

It probably takes a while to actually stop, because you have an actively running process. If you change "init:stop()" to "exit(stop)", it will terminate immediately:

```
3> cal:main().
{2009,1,1}
** exception exit: stop
     in function  cal:run_calendar/2
```

Answer (score 2):

Init:stop is asynchronous and it will take time to quit. An alternate way would be to wrap up the test in the call itself and use pattern matching to terminate the loop:

```
-module(cal).
-export([main/0]).

main() ->
    StartSec = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{2009,1,1},{0,0,0}}),
    EndSec = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{2009,12,31},{0,0,0}}),
    run_calendar(false, StartSec, EndSec).

run_calendar(true, _StartSec, _EndSec) ->
    finished;

run_calendar(false, CurSec, EndSec) -> 
    {Date,_Time} = calendar:gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(CurSec),
    io:format("~p~n", [Date]),
    NewSec = CurSec + 60*60*24,
    run_calendar(NewSec =< EndSec, NewSec, EndSec).
```

(or something similar, hopefully you get the idea)

Comment: Even though you had a fit-for-purpose disclaimer: "end" is a keyword and must be single-quoted if you want it as an atom.

Comment: Yes, I had null in my example and thought end would be better in the output. Do'h I've changed it now

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your if statement

You said

```
 if NewSec =< EndSec -> init:stop() end,
```

This is incorrect. You have to write something like:

```
if
    A =< B -> do something ...;
    true  -> do something else
end
```

The if syntax is

```
if
   Condition1 -> Actions1;
   Condition2 -> Actions2;
   ...
end
```

One of these conditions must always be true.

Why is this?

Erlang is a functional language, not a statement language. In an functional
language every expression must have a value. if is an expression, so it must have a value.

The value of (if 2 > 1 -> 3 end) is 3 but what is the value of
(if 1 > 2 -> 3 end) - answer it has no value - but it must have a value
everything must have a value.

In a statement language everything is evaluated for its side effect -so this would
be a valid construction.

In Erlang you will generate an exception.

So your code generates an exception - which you don't trap so you don't see it and 
init:stop() never gets called ...